# How to update my database generated by "code first from database"?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I just added two more columns to my database via SQL Server Management Studio. Now I'd like to use this in my WPF/C# application. How do I update the *.cs files in my project? I generated These files by adding a new item --> ADO.NET Entity Data Model --> Code first from database (using entity Framework 6).
For some reason I dont have a "model" or something like that.

Do I have to delete the files and add a new item?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ErikEJ said, you must delete the files and regenerate them. When you choose `code first from database` EF6 assumes that you wont change the model anymore (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, remove the files and regenerate them